# Possible to load entries into hosts.deny from text file?

Tags: hosts

I have around 96 million IP addresses that I have collected and routinely validate to be VPN providers, proxies, etc.  I want these blocked.  Currently, I am including the list formatted like `deny ip;` in nginx and that works perfectly.  I want to use this list on another server, but nginx isn't an option, and I don't trust apache to handle this without slowing down.  Is there a way to load this list into hosts deny via some command like aclexec or something? Are there other alternatives like setting up a DNSBL or using hosts.deny in conjunction with one?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```
sed "s/deny \(.*\);/ALL: \1/" list >> /etc/hosts.deny
```